# PyTorch dll issues for Caffe2

Tags: windows, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, caffe2

I am using a Windows 10 Machine and after re-installing Anaconda and all of the packages I had previously, including torchvision, torch and necessary dependencies, I am still getting this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\XXX\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I am using python 3.7.9 and:

- torchaudio=0.6.0=py37
- torchvision=0.7.0=py37_cpu
- tornado=6.0.4=py37he774522_1
- traitlets=5.0.5=py_0

I've looked into it quite a bit but feel like this should be an easy solve...

I do not have CUDA and have used this:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

as per instructed on the official website of [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/)

Comment: Getting the exact same error. I've tried everything and there's nothing about this anywhere. If you are/were able to find a solution please answer your own post!

Answer (score 1):

After a long time trying many things with Anaconda I decided to use bare python instead and I installed [Python 3.8.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-386/) and installed PyTorch from the link you provided and it finally worked even with CUDA support. Make sure to completely remove all Anaconda/Other Python version scripts from your path to ensure only the 3.8.6 version is used by your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install PyTorch with Anaconda and had the same error.
For me what solved the issue was to uninstall Pytorch using Pip (even though I installed it with conda) and then installing again with Pip as explains at [PyTorch guide](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Uninstall:

```
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torchvision
pip uninstall torchaudio
```

Install:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I uninstalled the pytorch in my machine using
"conda uninstall pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch"

Then did a clean installation using the following
"pip install torch===1.7.0 torchvision===0.8.1 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f [https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html%22)

I did not use conda for installation as it was persistently giving me the cpu version of pytorch.

Comment: awesome -- I did the same!

Answer (score 0):

To sum up all answers, using *conda* to install PyTorch tends to give the `[WinError 127]` error. Use *pip* to install *PyTorch* according to the instructions in the [official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).